# Must be exist or must be existed

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which one is grammatrical? (what I want to say is given a set of features, there is a set of features that must be selected)

> This feature set must be existed in any feature selection.
>
> This feature set must be exist in any feature selection.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct as they both employ two verbs together: *to be* and *to exist*.  You should use just one verb:

> This feature set must exist in any feature selection

Comment: The table must be removed after the dinner.
"Must be removed" also two verbs and incorrect?

Comment: Good point. The answer is that you can use remove in a passive sentence, but exist not. Exist can only be used actively.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

Neither version is correct, as they are attempts to put an intransitive verb in the passive voice, which cannot be done. The sentence should be written as follows:

> This feature set must exist in any feature selection.

---

**Painfully Long Answer:**

In the English language, there is a specific type of verb that is referred to as a *transitive* verb. Transitive verbs are verbs that can take a direct object; they are verbs that can be *done* to someone or something. These are the most common verbs (or, at least, most verbs have a transitive state), and they are the only verbs that can be used in the passive voice (though in the process they become *intransitive*).

For example:

> John kicks the ball.

In this sentence, "John" is the subject, "kicks" is the (transitive) verb, and "the ball" is the direct object. You can view it as the action of the "kick" is being *transferred* from John to the ball. The action starts with John, and it ends with the ball.

Now, if you want to make this sentence passive, you can do so by taking the direct object and making it the subject, and turning switching "kicks" into "is kicked":

> The ball is kicked by John.

Now "ball" is the subject, and "is kicked" is the verb. "By John" is now a prepositional phrase. The ball does not do anything to John. While the prepositional phrase "by John" contains important information, it is no longer filling a necessary role, so it can be (though it does not have to be) removed, to create a simple passive sentence.

As the action is now defined by its *passive* relationship to the subject (the ball), rather than its previously *active* relationship to the agent (John), the action can no longer be transferred to a direct object.

The verb is now, in its current state, what we would call *intransitive*.

There is also a select number of verbs which are innately intransitive. That is, even when used actively, they are contained exclusively to their relationship to the subject. Verbs such as "live", "die", "sleep", and, you guessed it, "exist", cannot have a direct object.

> John exists.

This sentence means, quite literally, that John is, in fact in existence. The verb is descriptive of John, and it cannot be transferred to a direct object.

Therefore, the (incorrect) sentence,

> John exists the ball.

makes no sense. The existence of John cannot be acted upon the ball. John's existence is limited exclusively to John.

The fact that there is no direct object means that there is no passive form for these verbs. There is no "ball" that is acted upon that can be turned into a subject for the sentence.

Looking at your examples, without all the extraneous details, if we are using the following sentence structure:

> Subject/verb/direct object.

your sentence would look like this:

> This feature set/must be exist(ed)/(no direct object).

If we turn this into a simpler present tense, it becomes clear that we're looking at a passive construction:

> This feature set is existed.

If we then turn that passive into an active construction, by turning the subject back into the direct object, and the agent (let's go with John, again) into the subject, the problem becomes quite evident:

> John exists this feature set.

The problem with the sentences you have provided is that they state that some unmentioned agent performs the action of existing the feature set.

And while this feature set can exist, *you cannot exist this feature set*.

You can *cause* the feature set to exist, but the transitive verb here is *cause*.

Therefore, the sentence needs to be presented in the active voice, without the pesky linking verb:

> This feature set must exist in any feature selection.

If you managed to make it through this lengthy, probably-incoherent explanation, great job! If you need me to clarify anything (or if I've made any terrible errors), let me know. If anyone feels this explanation was overkill, I really can't argue you on that.